# Installing Node.js through cPanel

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cpanel

(I'm new to Node.js and Socket.io)

I have my website hosted on a server and I would like to implement realtime communication between visitors. e.g: chat

I have seen many tutorials on how to install Node.js and use it with Socket.io, but all of them refer to localhost only.

How can I make Node.js run on my server? Can I do it through cPanel? Is there any tool like Terminal (i'm using a mac) to install it and make it run?

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done to solve this problem?

Comment: It's not a problem. It's a matter of not knowing how to do it. I have made a simple application to test node.js with socket.io locally. But now I want to know how to make it work on the server I have my website hosted on.

Comment: where have you hosted your app/website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hosting must support node.js/VPS server. Nowedays there are not many.
The most famous are nodejitsu, heroku and http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/